# Posting data to server every 15 minutes using Sync Adapter and Alarms

Tags: android, android-sqlite, alarmmanager, android-syncadapter

**Requirement -** I need to get the user's location coordinates every 15 minutes roughly and post it to the server. It is necessary to post data roughly at these intervals.

**Implementation -** I've made a sync adapter instead of using AlarmManager as it saves battery. I've set `ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync()` to sync my app every 15 minutes roughly which gets the current location and posts to server.

**Problem -** In case there's no internet connection, I want to continue taking the user's location every 15 minutes and save them in the local sqlite database. When the internet comes back again next time then I'll post all the saved locations in one go so that server data remains consistent and after that sync will resume as normal.

The **main problem** is that when there's no internet then the sync stops and I stop getting periodic sync callbacks in my app and I'm not able to save data in the local database. So what I want is that even when there's no internet I keep getting callbacks at regular intervals till the internet comes back and auto sync starts again. Can the sync adapter do that?

One **solution** I can think of is that I get a broadcast when the Internet stops and at that moment I start using the AlarmManager to start a service every 15 minutes and get the location and save to local database. And when the internet comes back on then I stop using the AlarmManager and go back to auto syncing.

**Solution 2 -** Provided by David Medenjak below. It is also efficient due to AlarmManager's `setInexactRepeating()` behavior which tries to imitate Sync adapter's behavior by scheduling Alarms for different apps together to reduce the number of times the CPU wakes up. Also it leads to a little simpler implementation. Would this the better way than the previous solution comparing the pros and cons?

Still any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using the platform's `LocationServices` API or the location services from Google Play Services?

Comment: location services from Google Play.

Comment: Are you using `FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation` or you are subscribing for continuous delivery via a `PendingIntent` ?

Comment: Whenever the sync starts i use FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation to get the location and send to server.

Comment: have you find the answer

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two things:

- Getting the user location every 15 minutes
- Syncing the data with the server

If you start mixing those you have a service and sync adapter that are both strongly dependent on each other, you have to check for states which of those has run and which should run. You might end up with the exact thing that you want (syncing every 15 minutes, just cache it if user is offline) but it will be hard to test and maintain.

---

*Always* use a service that is run every 15 minutes to store the current user location.

*Periodically* sync all updates to the server. This may also happen to be every 15 minutes, but you should not depend on this.

By having one part just storing the location and the other part just synchronizing the data you will have a much easier time handling things. And you also don't have to worry about internet connection or the interval of the synchronizations (since sync adapters are not guaranteed to run at exact times).

---

**Concerning battery life** *(comments)*

There should be no big difference whether a `SyncAdapter` uses gps and posts it immediately or a service persists it for the time being until the adapter syncs it. As soon as a task has to run every x minutes the device will have to wake up.

There might be slight improvements if the synchronization is run at a slower rate compared to the service, since the gps alone *might* not need any internet connection.

Comment: You're right, it'll have the same effect and I'll end up syncing to the server every 15 minutes but while the internet is active and assuming it will be most of the time, wouldn't it be better(battery wise) that a sync adapter is running instead of a service with wake locks. When the sync adapter runs I let it do all the work of getting location and posting it. So is it worth the effort or not battery wise? Because as you said running a service full time would be simple. But If I run a service then what's the point of sync adapter? I might as well post the data from that service too? Thanks!

Comment: @JyotmanSingh A sync adapter will also keep the device awake if you need it to run every 15 minutes. It can't run while the device is sleeping, neither can the service. You *might* have some overhead, but you won't really save much energy. *Note:* don't run the service 'full time' but start it every 15 minutes to run and do its job. Also you might save some energy running less syncs (like once a day), since gps alone might not need to create an internet connection (which *will* use battery)

Comment: Yes i'll be using a service every 15 minute through an AlarmManager and yes the sync adapter will also wake the device to sync but won't it be more efficient as it will try to match the sync time with other apps as well. It won't wake the device especially for my device. I don't mind if 15 min becomes 20 min or 10 min. And I can't sync once a day as I need to provide updates to the server every 15-20 min.

Comment: @JyotmanSingh You can also set the alarmmanager to call your service at inexact times to match other apps, and yes, you are right, it *might* be slightly more efficient, but you will have a harder time writing and maintaining it

Comment: I didn't know about AlarmManager's setInexactRepeating(). I guess it preserves some battery too. I guess I'll try both approaches and compare and meanwhile see if any other better solution emerges. I'll get back to you once I implement the approach. Thank you for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

`IntentService` - runs every 15 min (using `AlarmManager`) and saves the user location in the db and mark it as unsent.

`SyncAdapter` - runs every 15 min and ties to send all unsent locations to the server. On success mark the location as sent. Android will make sure it's only run when there is a internet connection.

Edit:
The key point is separating the two sub-tasks (also suggested by @David Medenjak):
1) Get a location update and store it in a db
2) Send the location updates to the server when there is a network connection.

The `FusedLocationProvider` has a method

```
requestLocationUpdates (GoogleApiClient client, LocationRequest request, PendingIntent callbackIntent)
```

for when your app is in the background. [Link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

> This method is suited for the background use cases, more specifically
>   for receiving location updates, even when the app has been killed by
>   the system.

You can use a `LocationRequest` to set the priority, interval, power consumption. [Link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest)

When you receive the pending intent, you can insert the location in the database and request a sync using the sync adapter.

Comment: Yes that is kind of the solution I've mentioned already. I'm looking for a better approach if any. Thank you